# r loop only returns one dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data structure like so:

| daynum | year1 | year2 | year3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1jan | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 2jan | 2 | 4 | 6 |

I want to coalesce the column titles to the day numbers into a new column, then stack the first 70 rows of each column into 1 new column.

```
daynum = c("day1", "day2", "day3", "day4")
year1 = c(1,2,3,4)
year2 = c(5,6,7,8)
year3 = c(7,8,9,10)

df <- data.frame(daynum, year1, year2, year3)
print(df)

  #create output data outside of loop
summerdata = data.frame()

for (i in names(df[,-1])){
  yeardate = data.frame(paste(i, df$daynum, sep="-"))
  sdata = data.frame(df[[i]])
  sur = sdata[1:70,]
  sy = yeardate[1:70,]
  endsummers = cbind(sy,sur)
  summerdata = rbind(summerdata,endsummers)
}
colnames(endsummers)=c("yeardate","summertemp")
print(endsummers)
```

all that returns in the first year1, and it's storing the numbers as text.

output should look like this:

```
      yeardate       summertemp
 [1,] "year1-day1"  85      
 [2,] "year1-day2"  87     
 [3,] "year1-day3"  79
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-daynum) %>%
  group_by(name) %>% slice(1:70) %>% ungroup() %>%  # only first 70 rows per year
  unite("daynum", 2:1, sep = "-") %>%
  arrange(daynum)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 12 × 2
   daynum     value
   <chr>      <dbl>
 1 year1-day1     1
 2 year1-day2     2
 3 year1-day3     3
 4 year1-day4     4
 5 year2-day1     5
 6 year2-day2     6
 7 year2-day3     7
 8 year2-day4     8
 9 year3-day1     7
10 year3-day2     8
11 year3-day3     9
12 year3-day4    10
```

Comment: ty Jon, I don't see where in the code you limit only the first n records (in my case 70). also, do you know why my loop is only returning the first loop?

Comment: @barker See my new answer below. Though `tidyverse` is definitely the better way to go here.

Comment: `slice(1:70)` is where the first 70 rows are selected

Answer (score 1):

So, there is actually nothing wrong with your loop, you are just changing the names of and printing `endsummers`, rather than `summerdata`. Also, to change to numeric, we can just add in `as.numeric` for `sur` when using `cbind`.

```
#create output data outside of loop
summerdata = data.frame()

for (i in colnames(df[,-1])){
  yeardate = data.frame(paste(i, df$daynum, sep="-"))
  sdata = data.frame(df[[i]])
  sur = sdata[1:70,]
  sy = yeardate[1:70,]
  endsummers = cbind(sy,as.numeric(sur))
  summerdata = rbind(summerdata,endsummers)
}

colnames(summerdata) <- c("yeardate","summertemp")
print(summerdata)
```

**Output**

```
head(summerdata, 15)

     yeardate summertemp
1  year1-day1          1
2  year1-day2          2
3  year1-day3          3
4  year1-day4          4
5  year1-day1          5
6  year1-day2          6
7  year1-day3          7
8  year1-day4          8
9  year1-day1          9
10 year1-day2         10
11 year1-day3         11
12 year1-day4         12
13 year1-day1         13
14 year1-day2         14
15 year1-day3         15
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(daynum = c("day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", 
"day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", 
"day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", 
"day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", 
"day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", 
"day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", 
"day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", 
"day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", 
"day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", 
"day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", 
"day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", 
"day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", "day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", 
"day2", "day3", "day4", "day1", "day2", "day3", "day4"), year1 = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 
68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 
84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 
100), year2 = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 
50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 
66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 
82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 
98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105), year3 = c(10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 
93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 
107, 108, 109, 110)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```